# How do I pass data to a layout which provides common controls for various pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently developing an ASP.Net project which provides a layout containing a lot of controls which should be rendered on every page the user visits. For example, a friends list should always be shown on the right of a page, as facebook uses for example.

Considering I want to avoid code reuse, I was planning to move the whole control to a shared page, which every other site is being rendered into.

However, I am now standing in front of the question how to get all the data from my backend to this control.

I read up a little bit and found out that I could use a model in the layout as well, but considering that this might not be the only control which might need data from a model, this model could grow big quickly and I would constraint myself to use a base model for any other model I will ever use in that project, as every page would need the required data for the controls in my shared view.

How could I deal with this? Is there a way to pass data to common controls in a shared page without a lot of downsides?

Or better, did I miss some other way to implement this, which would make everything easier for me?

Comment: the RenderAction html helper might be of use to you in your layout page.

Comment: RenderAction, partial views etc.

Comment: @John Do you know where I can find some documentation for this? I can't find anything on MSDN, just some blogs

Comment: Keep in mind you don't have to load all the data from the view either. You could use webapi and then, on the client, obtain the friends list data. This allows you to push a lot of the work onto the client, cache some data on the client and in the api, and keep your views and controllers cleaner by not having to load tons of data whenever you access the page. For example, a friends list might not show anything until someone clicks a button, which then loads the data into a visual list/modal, etc..

Comment: you can use partial view , or render partial view via jquery ajax. Or any js framwork.

Comment: @sossenbinder https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee839451(v=vs.100).aspx